# En que momento se ejecuta un metodo en Android Si solo esta definido

Tags: java, android

He visto varios códigos de java en específico de Android, pero tengo una duda, a continuación les presento el código de un `MainActivity`, en este se tiene la clase `MainActivity`, dentro de dicha clase se define otro método llamado OnStart, dicho método hace una llamada a una base de datos de firebase y pinta el valor del nodo en el dispositivo, es decir funciona perfectamente, lo que en realidad quiero entender es: En que momento se ejecuta el método? Yo solo veo la definición pero no veo que llamen al método con: `Onstar();`

No se si me explico, veo su definición pero no donde se invoca, cuando la app arranca se ejecuta dicho método lo cual siento no se debería de ejecutar hasta no poner la llamada a dicho método, a continuación el código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mFbTextView;
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mRootChild = mDatabaseReference.child("texto");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFbTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fbTextView);


}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mRootChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String texto = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        mFbTextView.setText(texto);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mFbTextView.setText("Dato de prueba");
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese método es parte del ciclo de vida la Activity como lo es OnCreate, OnDestroy, etc.  Por eso no es necesario llamarlo directamente si no que Android lo ejecutará automáticamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]